# How to populate combo box dynamically with Laravel (From Database)

Tags: laravel-5, dropdownbox

sorry guys if this is nothing to you all but I seem not to get it I have a drop down and would love to populate it from the database I am using laravel 5.2 and looked at almost all questions asked on this topic and most of it is on laravel 4. I tried populating my combo from database but kept on getting the same error "**ErrorException in 0fe8e1e2379436fb1f6f8c15a481341a7cff00e0.php line 22:
Undefined variable: callsign** " here is how I have done it form the **controller** l inserted this code:

```
     $callsign = \DB::table('drivers')->lists('Code');
    return view('spotCheck.create')->with('drivers', $callsign);
```

from my **view** here is the code:

```
    {!! Form::label('Code','Select a Driver') !!}
                {!! Form::select('Code', $callsign, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

the question is what I am i not doing write and whats up with the error how does my controller know where to populate drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the controller I had to do this

```
 $drive = DB::table('drivers')->lists('Code');
      return view('mypage',compact('drive'));
```

and on the view did this

```
 {!! Form::label ('Call Sign:',null, ['class'=>"control-label"])!!}
                          {!! Form::select('call_sign', $drive, null, ['class' => 'form-control' , 'id' => 'sel']) !!}
```